# How do I enable only a single Cloud SQL DB for a GCP service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-iam

I have a service account that should only have access to a single instance of Cloud SQL. In GCP, I've been trying to create a role with conditional access to the instance.

The instance name of the DB is test-sandboxy, and I've taken a screenshot of how I'm trying to create the role condition.
[image]

Is there a prefix that I need to put on the name? Or is there a directory where I can look up resource names?

Answer (score 3):

In IAM condition you need to put the fully qualified name of your resource. Here

```
projects/<ProjectNumber>/instances/<InstanceName>
```

Comment: The thing is that in the official [docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-resource-attributes) it's said that *the project number* must be included in the string not the *project id*. In my case nothing worked with the number but after I replaced it with id everything started to work fine

Comment: That's correct. Thanks for the remark, I updated my answer